# How do I execute my code through the terminal while using Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos, terminal, ide

I recently started using Xcode and I have been wondering how I could run everything on my terminal instead of using the bottom right corner of my IDE. Could someone explain this to me in baby steps.

Comment: Im hoping to make Xcode function like codelite in that regard.

Comment: which version of Xcode are you using ?

Comment: Now can you use terminal ?

Comment: Yes but a new problem has arisen as a result. My code works perfectly through Xcode but when I use the terminal option it only opens up the terminal, it doesn't even run the code. Then I try to run it again but Xcode then becomes unresponsive and therefore I have to force quit every time... The terminal was working for a little while and a bunch of strange things started occurring. I was having these issues on Catalina and I'm still having these issues on Big Sur.

Comment: i see but i think for this question it is a good idea accept as my answer for community :)

Answer (score 1):

Click on project name and click **Edit scheme** as below,

[image]

Click **Run** and click **Options** and choose **Use Terminal** below

[image]

Comment: Yes but a new problem has arisen as a result. My code works perfectly through Xcode but when I use the terminal option it only opens up the terminal, it doesn't even run the code. Then I try to run it again but Xcode then becomes unresponsive and therefore I have to force quit every time... The terminal was working for a little while and a bunch of strange things started occurring. I was having these issues on Catalina and I'm still having these issues on Big Sur.

Comment: hmm why dont you ask a new one ? looks like different issue